# Is there an Object-Oriented way to use standard reporting events?

Tags: abap

Is there an Object-Oriented way to create functionality for the standard reporting events like `INITIALIZATION` or `AT SELECTION-SCREEN`?

Comment: not really. It is a legacy technology, nobody would put effort into adapting it into OOP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there isn't an object-oriented alternative to the classic reporting events.

What I usually do when I am in an object-oriented mood but want to create a classic report with selection screen is to create a local class `lcl_main` and then write code like this:

```
INITIALIZATZION.
  lcl_main=>initialization( 
     CHANGING cv_date = p_date
              ct_bukrs = s_bukrs[] ).

AT SELECTION-SCREEN OUTPUT.
  lcl_main=>at_selection_screen_output( 
    CHANGING cv_date = p_date
             ct_bukrs = s_bukrs[] ).

START-OF-SELECTION.
  lcl_main=>start_of_selection( 
    iv_date = p_date
    it_bukrs = s_bukrs[] ).
```

This is also what [the most recent version of the official SAP documentation for `START-OF-SELECTION`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_756_index_htm/7.56/en-US/abapstart-of-selection.htm) does.